# Reading Invalid FileNames from a folder

Tags: delphi, file-io

I have an interesting problem. A client of ours recorded voice conversations from phone calls, but the filename that was given to the recording was invalid. Here is an example of the filename `123:123.wmv`

Believe it, Windows Media encoder created the file, and all the information is in the file, however Windows obviously don't recognise the filename, and only display it in the folder as `123` and the file is 0KB

Well from here it is edited: Thanks to Keith Miller that pointed me in the right direction I could write a function that will extract the stream names from the file and use it.

I've included a working copy of how to create two streams of data into a file, read the stream names and read the data from each stream. This is totally awesome, so I hope other people can use this as well.
My code ignores the main stream. If you write data into the main stream, it is best if you do not ignore it.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, uGeneralStuff;

type
  _FILE_STREAM_INFORMATION = record
    NextEntryOffset: cardinal;
    StreamNameLength: cardinal;
    StreamSize: int64;
    StreamAllocationSize: int64;
    StreamName: array[0..MAX_PATH] of WideChar;
  end;

  PFILE_STREAM_INFORMATION = ^_FILE_STREAM_INFORMATION;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    InfoBlock: _FILE_STREAM_INFORMATION;
    StatusBlock : record
      Status: Cardinal;
      Information: PDWORD;
    end;

    procedure CreateFile(FileName, Info: String);
    function ReadFile(FileName: String): String;
    function ReadStreams(filename: String): TStringList;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

function NtQueryInformationFile(FileHandle : Cardinal;
                                  IoStatusBlock : Pointer;
                                  FileInformation : Pointer;
                                  FileInformationLength : Cardinal;
                                  FileInformationClass : Cardinal
                                  ): Cardinal; stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll';
implementation

uses Math, StrUtils;
{$R *.dfm}

function TForm1.ReadStreams(filename: String): TStringList;
var
  iFH1: Integer;
  aFileName: array[0..MAX_PATH] of WideChar;
  aStreamName: String;
begin
Result := TStringList.Create;
iFH1 := FileOpen(filename, GENERIC_READ);
NtQueryInformationFile(iFH1, @StatusBlock, @InfoBlock, SizeOf(InfoBlock), 22);  // 22 Means FileStreamInformation
FileClose(iFH1);
while (1=1) do
  begin
  if InfoBlock.StreamNameLength = 0 then
    break;
  CopyMemory(@aFileName, @InfoBlock.StreamName, InfoBlock.StreamNameLength);
  aStreamName := Copy(aFileName, 1, PosEx(':', aFileName, 2) - 1);
  if aStreamName <> ':' then   //Ignore main stream, because I know I didn't write data in there
    Result.Add(aStreamName);
  if (InfoBlock.NextEntryOffset = 0) then
    break;
  InfoBlock := PFILE_STREAM_INFORMATION(PByte(@InfoBlock) + InfoBlock.NextEntryOffset)^;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aStreams: TStringList;
  I: Integer;
begin
aStreams := ReadStreams('C:\Temp\123');
for I := 0 to aStreams.Count - 1 do
  begin
  ShowMessage(ReadFile('C:\Temp\123' + aStreams[I]));
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateFile(FileName, Info: String);
var
  iFH1: Integer;
  Buffer: PAnsiString;
begin
  iFH1 := FileCreate(FileName);
  Buffer := PAnsiString(AnsiString(Info) + #0);
  FileWrite(iFH1, Buffer^, Length(Info));
  FileClose(iFH1);
end;

function TForm1.ReadFile(FileName: String): String;
var
  iFH1: Integer;
  Buffer: PAnsiChar;
  iFL: Integer;
  iBR, iCurPos, iReadSize: Integer;
begin
  iFH1 := FileOpen(FileName, GENERIC_READ);
  iFL := FileSeek(iFH1, 0, 2);
  FileSeek(iFH1, 0, 0);
  iReadSize := Min(iFL, 1024);
  Buffer := AllocMem(iReadSize + 1);
  iCurPos := 0;
  Result := '';
  while iCurPos < iFL do
    begin
    iBR := FileRead(iFH1, Buffer^, iReadSize);
    if iBR = -1 then
      break;
    Result := Result + Buffer;
    Inc(iCurPos, iBR);
    end;
  FileClose(iFH1);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateFile('C:\Temp\123:123.txt', 'This is TestFile 1');
  CreateFile('C:\Temp\123:345.txt', 'This is TestFile 2');
  ShowMessage(ReadFile('C:\Temp\123:123.txt'));
  ShowMessage(ReadFile('C:\Temp\123:345.txt'));
end;

end.
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the filename in double quotes?  So using one of the examples above, refer to the file as `'"C:\Temp\123:345.txt"'`.

Comment: @Jerry, Jaque has already stated that opening the file is not the problem. The problem is in *discovering the file's name*. Explorer and `FindFirstFile` both show only "123" without the rest of the name. You can't put something in quotes when you don't know what to put there.

Comment: Sorry I didn't catch that.  Well, have you tried the Unicode version of `FindFirstFileEx()`?  Remember to put `'\\?\'` at the beginning of the pattern you're looking for (so `'\\?\*'` for all files).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a : in a file name creates an alternate data stream in the file. See the article at 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763

In your example the file is called 123 and the stream is called 123.wmv. You could write a program to extract the stream from the file and rewrite it with a conventional file name.

The article at http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/alternate-streams.phtml should help.

Comment: @David - excellent! Goes to show that the command line is often mightier than the GUI.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the problem is David, that you need to know what the complete filename is to do this.

Comment: The reason why I chose this to be the answer is because it put me in the right direction. I will edit my question to put my findings

Comment: @DavidHeffernan your copy statement does not work `C:\Temp>copy "123:123.txt" 123.txt
123:123.txt
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`
Even without the " it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

<strike>`FindFirst` uses a `TSearchRec` record to return the file properties. There you have a `FindData` element (`TWin32FindData`), which contains some extra properties like the alternate name of the file. Perhaps you can use that.</strike>

**Edit**: I found a page that contains a unit with a function named `ADSFindFirst` (which, incidently, contains `NtQueryInformationFile` neatly wrapped internally.) I don't have Delphi here but looks promising: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=7167

Comment: The "alternate name" is the short file name, where *Program Files* becomes *Progra~1*, for example. That won't help in listing what Jaques is looking for.

Comment: Tried it. Does not give me any more info

Comment: Yes, he stated he need the exact name, but didn't say why he needs it. If it is for display purposes only this won't do. But if he needs it in string form so he can open it elsewhere, this may be of help.

Comment: BTW, I think the Nt* functions are declared somewhere in the Jedi libs

Comment: Plain old `FindFirstFile` will give the exact name *of the file*, but it will not list any of the alternate data streams, which is the location of the customer's data. If `NtQueryInformationFile` is right, then could you tell which `File_Information_Class` value gives the desired information?

Comment: @RobKennedy - you get a buffer with stream information blocks and you traverse it until you get a zero-length one. Not sure how to tell which is the "right" one.

Comment: @RobKennedy [FileStreamInformation](http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/alternate-streams.phtml)

Answer (score 1):

As @KeithMiller [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10536263/11480), you are creating the file `'C:\Temp\123'` with an empty main stream and two alternate streams.

My quick attempt at Delphi XE (so - Unicode!) code to show the stream names, based on the [article](http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/alternate-streams.phtml):

```
type
  NTSTATUS = Cardinal;
  TFileInformationClass = (
    FileDirectoryInformation                  = 1,
    FileFullDirectoryInformation,
    FileBothDirectoryInformation,
    FileBasicInformation,
    FileStandardInformation,
    FileInternalInformation,
    FileEaInformation,
    FileAccessInformation,
    FileNameInformation,
    FileRenameInformation,
    FileLinkInformation,
    FileNamesInformation,
    FileDispositionInformation,
    FilePositionInformation,
    FileFullEaInformation,
    FileModeInformation,
    FileAlignmentInformation,
    FileAllInformation,
    FileAllocationInformation,
    FileEndOfFileInformation,
    FileAlternateNameInformation,
    FileStreamInformation,
    FilePipeInformation,
    FilePipeLocalInformation,
    FilePipeRemoteInformation,
    FileMailslotQueryInformation,
    FileMailslotSetInformation,
    FileCompressionInformation,
    FileObjectIdInformation,
    FileCompletionInformation,
    FileMoveClusterInformation,
    FileQuotaInformation,
    FileReparsePointInformation,
    FileNetworkOpenInformation,
    FileAttributeTagInformation,
    FileTrackingInformation,
    FileIdBothDirectoryInformation,
    FileIdFullDirectoryInformation,
    FileValidDataLengthInformation,
    FileShortNameInformation,
    FileIoCompletionNotificationInformation,
    FileIoStatusBlockRangeInformation,
    FileIoPriorityHintInformation,
    FileSfioReserveInformation,
    FileSfioVolumeInformation,
    FileHardLinkInformation,
    FileProcessIdsUsingFileInformation,
    FileNormalizedNameInformation,
    FileNetworkPhysicalNameInformation,
    FileIdGlobalTxDirectoryInformation,
    FileIsRemoteDeviceInformation,
    FileAttributeCacheInformation,
    FileNumaNodeInformation,
    FileStandardLinkInformation,
    FileRemoteProtocolInformation,
    FileMaximumInformation
  );
  PIOStatusBlock = ^TIOStatusBlock;
  TIOStatusBlock = packed record
    case Boolean of
      False: (Status: NTSTATUS; P: Pointer;);
      True: (Information:  ULONG_PTR);
  end;
  PFileStreamInformation = ^TFileStreamInformation;
  TFileStreamInformation = packed record
    NextEntryOffset: ULONG;
    StreamNameLength: ULONG;
    StreamSize: LARGE_INTEGER;
    StreamAllocationSize: LARGE_INTEGER;
    StreamName: array[0..0] of Char;
  end;

type
  TNtQueryInformationFile = function(FileHandle: THandle; IoStatusBlock: PIOStatusBlock;
  FileInformation: Pointer; Length: ULONG; FileInformationClass: TFileInformationClass): NTSTATUS; stdcall;

procedure GetAlternateFileStreamNames(const FileName: string; StreamNames: TStrings);
var
  hNT, hFile: THandle;
  NtQueryInformationFile: TNtQueryInformationFile;
  Buffer: array[Word] of Byte;
  ioStatus: TIOStatusBlock;
  P: PFileStreamInformation;
  S: string;
  L: Integer;
begin
  hNT := GetModuleHandle('ntdll.dll');
  if hNT = 0 then
    Exit;
  NtQueryInformationFile := GetProcAddress(hNT, 'NtQueryInformationFile');
  if @NtQueryInformationFile = nil then
    Exit;

  FillChar(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), 0);
  hFile := CreateFile(PChar(FileName), 0, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
  try
    if NtQueryInformationFile(hFile, @ioStatus, @Buffer[0], SizeOf(Buffer), FileStreamInformation) = 0 then
    begin
      StreamNames.BeginUpdate;
      try
        StreamNames.Clear;
        P := @Buffer[0];
        while Assigned(P) do
        begin
          SetString(S, P^.StreamName, P^.StreamNameLength div SizeOf(Char));
          // strip trailing :$DATA
          L := Length(S);
          if (L >= 6) and (StrComp(@S[L - 5], ':$DATA') = 0) then
            Delete(S, L - 5, L);
          StreamNames.Add(S);

          if P^.NextEntryOffset = 0 then
            P := nil
          else
            P := Pointer(Integer(P) + P^.NextEntryOffset); //@Buffer[P^.NextEntryOffset];
        end;
      finally
        StreamNames.EndUpdate;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hFile);
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  StreamNames: TStringList;
begin
  StreamNames := TStringList.Create;
  try
    GetAlternateFileStreamNames('C:\Temp\123', StreamNames);
    ShowMessage(StreamNames.Text);
  finally
    StreamNames.Free;
  end;
end;
```

For the file created by your code as posted in your question, it shows the following entries:

1. `':'` - unnamed main stream, I think
2. `':123.txt'` - the first alternate stream
3. `':345.txt'` - the second alternate stream

Totally untested and weird, also it needs to be modified for D2007 and earlier.